# Functional programming functions using 2 lists in D

Tags: functional-programming, d

If I have 2 lists:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
list2 = [10, 25, 35, 58];
```

and I want to get a list which has products of corresponding elements of 2 lists;

In Python one can do:

```
outlist = list(map(lambda a,b: a*b, list1, list2))
```

However, in D, I know of following method:

```
import std.stdio; 
void main(){
    auto list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    auto list2 = [10, 25, 35, 58];
    int[] outlist; 
    foreach(i, item; list1){    
        outlist ~= item*list2[i];
    }
    writeln(outlist); 
}
```

My questions are:

Q1: Can one keep both lists as argument of foreach?

Q2: How to multiply corresponding elements of 2 lists using map function?

Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is to use [`zip`](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#zip) to combine the elements of the two lists (or [dynamic arrays](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/arrays.html) as they are known in D) to a single array of [tuples](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/tuples.html) before applying `map` or `foreach`. The tuple elements can be accessed with a zero based index (i.e. `a[0]` and `a[1]` in this example).

```
import std.algorithm.iteration : map;
import std.range : zip;
import std.stdio : writeln;

void main() {
  auto list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  auto list2 = [10, 25, 35, 58];

  // Question #2
  auto list3 = zip(list1, list2).map!(a => a[0] * a[1]);

  writeln(list3);

  // Question #1
  typeof(list1) list4;
  foreach(a; zip(list1, list2)) {
    list4 ~= a[0] * a[1];
  }

  writeln(list4);
}
```

The code above prints twice:

```
[10, 50, 105, 232]
```

as expected.